# Digital Personal UareU 4500 and Linux

Tags: java, sdk, fingerprint

I meet some problem on the Fingerprint SDK of Digital Personal UareU 4500
Platform : Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS / Java.

When I`m try to run my program, it throw this Exception :

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no otmcjni in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.MatchingLibrary.<clinit>(MatchingLibrary.java:16)
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.Matcher.<clinit>(Matcher.java:8)
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.processing._impl.DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl$EnrollmentImpl.<init>(DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl.java:40)
```

Can anyone give a help ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

this is because libraries are not in the correct place...please check in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file of the principal jar file and see where are pointing the dependences jar files ..
normally i see that is pointing to the same place of the jar file so copy all dependents jar in same place of main jar file and try

hope this helps